# How to stop requesting tiles after a certain zoom level in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, xyz, xyz-tiles

I am using OpenLayers to create a map. The base of the map is being created using XYZ as the source. I only have till certain zoom level and i was wondering if there is any way to make the browser stop requesting more tiles after a certain zoom level.

> GET http://localhost:4200/assets/tile/14/5/3.png 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 3):

`ol.source.XYZ` has a `maxZoom` option

```
source: new ol.source.XYZ({
  url: 'http://localhost:4200/assets/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
  maxZoom: 13
})
```

Comment: This does not allow the user to zoom more than 13, i want the user to be able to zoom on the last received tiles.

Comment: It doesn't restrict view zoom.  If you don't have tiles at level 14 you would need to let OpenLayers browser zoom a level which does exist.

Comment: I tried this, it does not work

Comment: It is working here https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/WNeaVeq  The view is zoomed to level 15 even though tiles are restricted to level 13.,